# Windows screen/desktop video capture (screencast) with crop (and output video of the crop region size)?

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I need an application, that will allow me to select a region of the desktop with the mouse - in other words, a "cropped" region, - and then record a video/screencast, with mouse pointer etc included, *only* of the "cropped" region. I'm looking for a gratis option, limited capture time is OK - loging in to use is not, watermarks are not.

I actually found one program which is *almost* there - (Open Broadcaster Software) OBS Studio; it is actually great, except for this:

- https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/despite-cropping-still-records-full-screen-but-black.56880/

That is, if you have 1462x865 desktop resolution, that will be taken to be the default size of the video; that will remain the size, even if you crop (in which case you'll get black areas in the video) - or you can scale the crop the size of the output video; but there is no easy way to scale the output size of the video to the size of the crop (you'd have to go to Edit/Transform/Edit Transform..., copy the crop settings from there, then calculate the crop size manually, then enter that manually in Settings/Video/Base (Canvas) and Output (Scaled) Resolution). So, it is definitely not straightforward to get a video output with frame size in pixels equal to the crop size in pixels.

So is there an application that allows this a bit more easily? As in, if I select a region of 300x400 pixels on the screen, and hit record, I get a video with frames 300x400 pixels in size?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Debut Video Capture](https://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html) seems to work, and there is a free version for non-commercial use - but very quickly, it ends up preventing the record feature in demo mode.